# Handle for close event of PowerPoint app in the add-in (JS)

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I was looking for a way to handle the closing event of the PowerPoint when developing an Add-in.

The only ones that were a bit close was the fact that we can detect the visibility change of the add-in with

```
Office.addin.onVisibilityModeChanged((args) => {});
```

Is there anything else that it can be used to detect the closing of the PowerPoint app? I need to send data to the server or ask the user if he wants the changes to be saved.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are no other events. You can use the [onVisibilityModeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.addin?view=common-js-preview#office-office-addin-onvisibilitymodechanged-member(1)) handler for that:

```
Office.addin.onVisibilityModeChanged().then(function (args) {
  if (args.visibilityMode = "Taskpane") {
     // Code that runs whenever the task pane is made visible.
  } else if (args.visibilityMode === "Hidden") {
     // Show prompt to the user.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the right approach, and please notice that [Office.BeforeDocumentCloseNotification interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.beforedocumentclosenotification?view=powerpoint-js-preview) is on preview now, please consider using it with caution in production environments